# get the ID of a link when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the ID of a link when clicked. I don't want the link to go anywhere, I just want the ID.

So far, the code does not write anything to the console.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
    $("#webLinks a").on('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked: ' + a.id);
    });

    <div id="webLinks">
        <div class="linkRows">
            <div name="link1">
                <a id="webLink1" href="#" name="www.google.com">Google</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
console.log('clicked: ' + a.id);
```

to:

```
console.log('clicked: ' + this.id);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vJWAT/)**

`this` refers to the element receiving the click. In your original code, `a` doesn't refer to the anchor (or anything) so it's undefined.

Also, make sure your code is being run after the elements exist on the page or from within a document ready call:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `this.id` instead of `a.id`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3qZF/)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#webLinks a").on('click', function () {
       $(this).attr('id');
});
```